# Getting Minimum output then track the inputs

Tags: c#, mathematical-optimization

i have some inputs represent locations, apply them on an equation to get an output for each location then i wanna choose the minimum output, how can i track back this minimum value i got to get the input location related to the minimum ?

The code is getting the input information from an Excel Sheet

```
for (int m = 0; m < Weights.Count; m++)
        {
            int offset = m * ListCranelocations.Count;

            for (int i = 0; i < ListCranelocations.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < ListPickLocations.Count; j++)
                {
                    double x = ListCranelocations[i].Lat - ListPickLocations[j].Lat;
                    double y = ListCranelocations[i].Lng - ListPickLocations[j].Lng;
                    R1[i] = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x, 2) + Math.Pow(y, 2));

                    if (R1[i] > Clearance)
                    {
                       result1[i + offset, j] = Weights[m] * R1[i];

                        //Console.WriteLine(result1[i, j]);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```